# Strange segfault with linked list

Tags: c++

Had this working on visual studios most recent version, tried to sent to school server with makefile and this error on valgrind stopped at process first headPtr == nullptr   when attempting to add int to empty list

segfault

It said to add some more details so I guess Ill keep on writing till it lets me submit, I don't know what else to say, if someone wants to try runnuing it I have menu and valid driver functions but testing could be done with out them.

```
#include "list.hpp"

int main()
{
    menu();
}
list: main.o list.o valid.o menu.o  node.o  
    g++ -std=c++0x -g main.o list.o valid.o menu.o  node.o   -o list
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++0x -g -c main.cpp
node.o: node.cpp 
    g++ -std=c++0x -g -c node.cpp

list.o: list.cpp
    g++ -std=c++0x -g -c list.cpp


menu.o: menu.cpp 
    g++ -g -std=c++0x -c menu.cpp

valid.o: valid.cpp 
    g++ -g -c -std=c++0x valid.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o list
```

valgrind errors[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iSBq.png)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM9az.png



#include"list.hpp"


List::List()
{
    Node* headPtr = nullptr;
    Node* tailPtr = nullptr;
}
List::~List()
{

    if (headPtr != nullptr)

    {
        while (headPtr != nullptr)
        {
            Node* toDel = headPtr;
            headPtr = headPtr->getNext();
            delete toDel;
        }
    }
 }

void List::addHead(int add)
{

    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    Node* nll = nullptr;
    nodePtr->setVal( add);//put in data
    nodePtr->setPrev(nll); // always do ->make prev( before new head) null as is now new head
    if (headPtr == nullptr)//empty list
    {
        nodePtr->setNext(nll);//nothing next prev already null

        headPtr = nodePtr;//only node set head
        tailPtr = nodePtr;//set tail
    }
    else //nodes exists already
    {
        nodePtr->setNext(headPtr);//next of new head is old head 
        (headPtr)->setPrev(nodePtr); //prev old head new haed
        headPtr = nodePtr;//change headPtr
    }

    traverse();

}

void List::addTail(int add)//takes pointer to pointer to tail node
{
    Node* nll = nullptr;

    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->setNext(nll);//will be last node
    nodePtr->setVal(add);//put in data
    if (tailPtr == nullptr)
    {
        headPtr = nodePtr;//only node set head
        tailPtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr->setPrev(nll); //nothing there
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr->setPrev(tailPtr);
        tailPtr->setNext(nodePtr);
        tailPtr = nodePtr;
    }
    traverse();

}
    /*if (headPtr != NULL)//if this is NOT first element added

{//then stick new node to beginning of list b4 swaping head

    (headPtr)->setPrev(nodePtr);
}
headPtr = nodePtr; //reset head to new node

if (tailPtr == NULL)
{
    tailPtr = nodePtr;//if first node set tail


}*/
    /*
        tailPtr->setNext(nodePtr) ;//make link to old tail ->newtail
    }
    tailPtr = nodePtr;
    if (headPtr == NULL)
    {
        headPtr = nodePtr;//set head if first ele
    }*/






void List::delFirst()
{
    Node* nll = nullptr;

    if (headPtr == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The list was already empty." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (headPtr->getNext() == nullptr || tailPtr->getPrev()== nullptr)//one node only
    {
        delete headPtr;
        headPtr = nullptr;
        tailPtr = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        //Node* tmp = headPtr;
        headPtr = (headPtr)->getNext();
        delete headPtr->getPrev();
        headPtr->setPrev(nll);
    }
    traverse( );

}
void List::delLast( )
{
    Node* nll = nullptr;

    if (tailPtr == nullptr)//empty
    {
        std::cout << "The list was already empty." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (headPtr->getNext() == nullptr || tailPtr->getPrev() == nullptr)//one node only?
    {
        delete tailPtr;
        headPtr = nullptr;
        tailPtr = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {   
        tailPtr = (tailPtr)->getPrev();//move back one
        delete  tailPtr->getNext();
        tailPtr->setNext(nll);

    }
    traverse();

}

void  List::reverseTrav()
{
    Node* tmp = tailPtr;
    if (tmp == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The list is empty." << std::endl;

    }
    while (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << tmp->getVal() << " " ;
        tmp = tmp->getPrev();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void  List::traverse()
{
    Node* tmp = headPtr;
    if (tmp == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The list is empty." << std::endl;

    }
    while (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << tmp->getVal() << " " ;
        tmp = tmp->getNext();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
void menu()
{
    List list;


    Menu myMenu;

    myMenu.addItem("Enter 1 to add integer to front\nEnter 2 to add integer to back \nEnter 3 to delete from front \nEnter 4 to delete from back \nEnter 5 to traverse in reverse \n Enter 6 to quit");//itm 1
    myMenu.addItem("enter integer to add to front (limits +/-1000000)");//item 2
    myMenu.addItem("enter integer to add to back (limits +/-1000000)");//item 3;
    //myMenu.addItem("enter number:");//item 4;
    //myMenu.addItem("enter number to find triangle value from");//item 5;
    bool play = true;

    do
    {
        myMenu.displayChoice(1);
        int choice = myMenu.getIntAnswer(1, 5);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            myMenu.displayChoice(2);
            int ans = myMenu.getIntAnswer(-1000000, 1000000);
            list.addHead(ans);
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {

            myMenu.displayChoice(3);
            std::cout << "upper and lower limits of numbers to be summed -100000000 and 100000000" << std::endl;
            int ans = myMenu.getIntAnswer(-1000000, 1000000);
            list.addTail(ans);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            list.delFirst();

        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {

            list.delLast();
        }
        else if (choice == 5)

        {
            list.reverseTrav();
        }
        else if (choice == 6)
        {
            play = false;
        }
    } while (play == true);

}


#ifndef LIST_HPP
#define LIST_HPP

#include "node.hpp"

class List
{
private:
    Node *headPtr;
    Node *tailPtr;
public:
    List();
    void addHead( int);
    void addTail( int);
    void delFirst();
    void delLast();
    void reverseTrav();
    void traverse();
    ~List();
};
void menu();

#endif
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include "menu.hpp"
class Node
{
private:
    Node * next;
    int val;
    Node * prev;
public:
    Node * getPrev();
    Node * getNext();
    void setNext(Node*);
    void setPrev(Node*);
    int getVal();
    void setVal(int);
};

#endif
#include "node.hpp"
Node * Node::getPrev()
{
    return prev;
}
Node * Node::getNext()
{
    return next;
}
void Node::setNext(Node* nIn)
{
    next = nIn;
}
void Node::setPrev(Node* pIn)
{
    prev = pIn;
}

int Node::getVal()
{
    return val;
}
void Node::setVal(int vIn)
{
    val = vIn;
}
```

Comment: Stop doing manual memory management (`new`/`delete`) and learn about smart pointers and all the container classes already available in the standard library. This reads like C++ fron the '90s. That's not how modern C++ is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind is trying to tell you the answer! If you ever see:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)

You're almost certainly doing something wrong. In this case, Valgrind is talking about:

```
if (headPtr == nullptr)//empty list
```

But you initialize `headPtr`...don't you? Let's see your constructor:

```
List::List()
{
    Node* headPtr = nullptr;
    Node* tailPtr = nullptr;
}
```

Uh oh! You create two new `Node*` and set them to `nullptr`, but you never modify the `headPtr` and `tailPtr` members of your class! Remember that in C++ you can easily shadow a variable by declaring a new one with the same name in a sub-scope.

Drop the `Node*`'s in your constructor so you actually initialize the member variables, or even better, use a field initialization list so you don't even have to worry about this!

```
List::List() : headPtr(nullptr), tailPtr(nullptr) { }
```

Comment: holy moly where were you last night :0

Comment: you are my savior!

Comment: @DavePassaro haha happy to help!

Comment: @DavePassaro Valgrind is indeed telling you the issue...but you can get the compiler to tell you these things, you don't need Valgrind for this. `-Wshadow` for gcc in particular. Might even be in with `-Wall`.

Comment: the point to realize is that in your constructor you were creating 2 things called headPtr and tailPtr, these have nothing to do with the member fields of you class. If you ramp up the warning level you would get a warning perhaps that you were masking out the class variables.